# Can't execute shell script from php. Returns code 126

Tags: php, shell

I'm trying to execute a shell script from my website using a PHP script but I keep getting this output:

**Output: Array ( ) Return: 126**

I know it has something to do with permissions, but I granted every permission possible ^^' (777)

Here is the php source code:

```
exec('importData.sh', $output, $return);
echo "Output: ";
print_r($output);
echo " Return: " . $return . "</pre>";
```

The importData file contains this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello";
```

This is just a test script, more is to come ...
The shell script is located on a remote server, where my website is.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html

> If a command is found but is not executable, the return status is 126.

Maybe you did have granted the permission to execute your script, but the user executing it simply do not have permission to execute bash, or even echo

If you don't have the mean to check your bash location or permissions, you can try to remove the shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`), it's not very clean but most of the time it's not needed if your script is simple and can be executed with any shell

Comment: ..... So how can I solve this problem? .... I don't have much experience in mixing php and shell scripts ....

Comment: Well it depends on the level of permission you have on the remote server. If it's not self hosted you should see with your hosting if the user executing the script (probably "www-data" if you use Apache) can execute bash.
If you have access to the server you can try a `ls -l /bin/bash` (if it's the good location) to check permissions

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually I tried to print the errors and found out that the problem is with the line: #!/bin/bash, error: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Is your bash really in `/bin/bash` ? Did you try your script without the shebang line ?

Comment: It works without the line ... so weird ... well thanks for your help I was really stuck ^^'

Comment: Well the shebang is not mandatory, it gives a hint to which interpreter should be used, but if you are not sure of it's location it can makes things worse. I will edit my answer.